# C# adding click event to TableCell in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, tablecell

I'm trying to use the codebehind to add a click event to a TableCell..I basically want the user to be able to click a cell and cause a server side click event so that I can call a method with the GUID of the item in the cell...seems this functionality should already be built-in but I've been unable to find much in the way of instruction.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported in ASP.Net. As a work arround, I would suggest adding a LinkButton without text and try to extend it to all the cell with `Absolute`  value for `Position`.

Then use the button's click event.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can add an attribute to the cell from code-behind.

First make sure the cell is marked `runat="Server"` in markup

Then in code behind add attributes such as

```
YOURCELLNAME.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.backgroundImage='';");
```

or

```
YOURCELLNAME.Attributes.Add("onclick","NameOfAJavascriptFunctionHere");
```

Comment: This doesn't work in ASP.NET. TableCell does not recognize javascript as an attribute.